# Is it possible to check Morality without previous Conflict?

Tags: star-wars-force-and-destiny

Is it possible to check Morality at the end of a game session if previously the character hasn't earned Conflict? In other words, if the character stays in the Light Side at every moment and do not fall under the Dark Side temptations he has no chance to improve his Morality, but only by performing some dark or conflictive actions or by indirect ways, like a fear check result.

If I'm not wrong, he would be able to check Morality if other character in the group has earned Conflict, but what in a solo game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

The rules for Morality does not exclude characters who did not earn conflict.

> A Player Character’s Morality has a chance of changing at the end of each game session. **A PC’s actions** during the session **may increase** the probability that his Morality will rise or fall
>
> The **more Conflict** a PC accumulates, the **greater the chance his Morality will decrease** at the end of the session.

Then, it further explains what happens to your morality based on the amount of conflict generated (p. 36):

> Over the course of a game session, **a PC may earn no Conflict at all**, as much as ten Conflict, or even more. At the end of the session, each player tallies up the Conflict his character has earned and then rolls a d10 die. (...)
>
> If the roll result is **greater than the amount of Conflict** he has earned, however, he subtracts his Conflict from his roll result and **increases his Morality by that number**.

So it's completely possible that a PC earned no conflict at all, so his Morality will certainly increase at the end of that session.